# Visual studio 2011 misses applying color scheme on XML documents

Tags: visual-studio

The Visual Studio 11 installed on my system does not apply the color scheme related to XML for the related documents (.config, .xml).

[image: Web.config file in VS2011 IDE]

I tried checking the `Tools->Options-Fonts and Colors`, but that screen is missing all display items related to XML
[image: Fonts and Colors missing XML related entries]

I have tried the following to troubleshoot this issue and have failed:

1. Tools -> Import and Export settings... -> Reset all settings
2. Tools -> Import and Export settings... -> Import (few of my favorites from http://studiostyl.es/)

I have installed further version of VS2011 on virtual machines and they seem to apply the proper color schemes for XML files, and also my VS2010 on the same machine works fine with the XML.

Do let me know of anything that you may think is causing this issue. In the already bleak color scheme of VS2011 working on my instance with XML files are quite unbearable :)

Comment: What editor are you opening the XML with? As in right click -> Open With, what's the default?

Comment: I am not explicitly opening editor (using the default double click). I went ahead and checked the `Open with...` option, currently `Automatic Editor Selector (XML) (Default)` was highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Beta and upgrading to RC resolved the issue.